# How to update and select In same query

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I want to change the value of row when its download

```
  //Please tell me how to update and select data in  in same query
  $query =  "UPDATE `site` SET status = 1 JOIN SELECT `url` FROM  `site` 
             LIMIT 0,10";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $developer_records[] = $row;
  }
  //Download the file
  $filename = "export.xls";
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
```

> Blockquote

```
  if(!empty($developer_records)) {
     foreach($developer_records as $record) {
          echo $record[url]."\n";
          mysql_query("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **not** `update` and `select` in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` and `SELECT` are two separate operations and you cannot do both in one query.

However, you can group the operations together in **stored procedures** if you need.

Here are some examples of stored procedures:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/stored-procedures.html

Here's a handy review of it:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php

Please note: stored procedures are NOT the same as transactions.  I.e. they do not provide explicit commit control.